# Google App Engine Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a task queue with several tasks. If I delete a particular task from Admin Console, it disappears from the task queue but GAE doesnt terminate it. The task is still being executed in the background. 
Is this a common behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I see the same behavior. Seems you can only delete pending tasks from the admin console. Once they've started they continue to run until they finish or hit an exception (could be as long as 10 minutes with the new update).

I've noticed they don't stop on version upgrades either, which is a little weird if you aren't expecting it... if the task takes a long time you end up with handlers running in two versions of the app simultaneously. It makes sense though.

Comment: This is intended behaviour: Tasks in the admin console only reflect those that haven't run yet (when the page was loaded).